# failed to create cluster: failed to join node with kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, ubuntu-22.04, calico, kind

I've been told my `k8ssandra` people that the following errors are related to `kubernetes`

What do I have to do to detect, and solve, the issue?

`kind` seems working fine:

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kind create cluster
Creating cluster "kind" ...
 ✓ Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.27.3)  
 ✓ Preparing nodes   
 ✓ Writing configuration  
 ✓ Starting control-plane ️ 
 ✓ Installing CNI  
 ✓ Installing StorageClass  
Set kubectl context to "kind-kind"
You can now use your cluster with:
kubectl cluster-info --context kind-kind

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl cluster-info --context kind-kind
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://127.0.0.1:41237
CoreDNS is running at https://127.0.0.1:41237/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kind get clusters
kind
```

But I'm getting these errors :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~/go/bin/k8ssandra-operator# scripts/setup-kind-multicluster.sh --clusters 1 --kind-worker-nodes 5
Creating 1 clusters...
Creating cluster 1 out of 1
Creating cluster "k8ssandra-0" ...
 ✓ Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.25.3) 
 ✓ Preparing nodes        
 ✓ Writing configuration  
 ✓ Starting control-plane ️ 
 ✓ Installing CNI  
 ✓ Installing StorageClass  
 ✗ Joining worker nodes  
Deleted nodes: ["k8ssandra-0-worker" "k8ssandra-0-worker3" "k8ssandra-0-worker5" "k8ssandra-0-control-plane" "k8ssandra-0-worker2" "k8ssandra-0-worker4"]
ERROR: failed to create cluster: failed to join node with kubeadm: command "docker exec --privileged k8ssandra-0-worker5 kubeadm join --config /kind/kubeadm.conf --skip-phases=preflight --v=6" failed with error: exit status 1
```

This is the complete log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t0LAX5TtunnNYLbCVXeQ1x1pBIIL9dxv/view?usp=sharing

This is the ouput of cluster-info dump :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RPenPw6ki6cCORMrpfOJqm89wFo_G-xN/view?usp=drive_link

What should I do in order to detect and solve the root cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is there another instance and or other software running on that node?

```
E1031 10:25:03.813191  567933 server.go:179] "Failed to listen and serve" err="listen tcp 0.0.0.0:10250: bind: address already in use"
```

There are some ports that are already in use, so the installation fails.

Since you are using `--kind-worker-nodes 5` - it is likely the case, that fixed published ports are issuing this.